# Calculating average scene brightness in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, brightness

I'm currently implementing automatically adapting exposure for use with HDR in OpenGL. For this I need to retrieve the average brightness of all pixels in the previous frame.

I've not managed to find any solid explanations of how to do this. As far as I can see there are two ways to go about it.

1. Use glReadPixels to copy the framebuffer to memory and average them on the CPU. This is likely to be painfully slow and doesn't make good use of the GPU.
2. Take the frame and render it to successively smaller FBOs using linear filtering. This lets the GPU do most of the work but it's going to require a lot of FBOs (roughly 10 for a 1080p screen).

There has got to be a better way of getting average scene brightness. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options that come into my mind:

- Using glGenerateMipmap, which calculates the average of a 2x2 window, leaving you with the average scene brightness at the smallest level. This can be retrieved using textureLod function in a shader. Since each mipmap level has half the size of the previous one, the correct level will be log2(max), where max is the returned value of GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE.
- Using compute shaders to do basically the same thing glGenerateMipmap does, but with a bigger window size, which could potentially be faster (although I never tested this).

Comment: If I generate mipmaps for the frame how do I read back a pixel from the smallest mipmap in the program code? Sampling the previous frame in the tone mapping shader isn't really an option since the texture was cleared and reused for the current frame. I'd like to just read the brightness in the program code after rendering a frame, store it and then pass it to the relevant shader as a uniform during the next frame.

Comment: After reading the spec I think this would be achieved with glGetTexImage. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Your Option 2 is not much different from using [`glGenerateMipmap`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glGenerateMipmap.xml) on the texture, just that you don't need to hassle with any client side objects like FBOs. So basically, rendering to mipmap level 0 of the texture, letting the GL generate the mipmap pyramid, and reading back just the highest level 1x1 image is probably the easiest way to get some approximation of the average color value.